# A problem with charging

Tags: battery-charging

I am beginner in this field. I made a charger with 7805, 10 uF, 100 uF, 100 nF capacitors and 9 V non-chargeable + 3 V rechargeable batteries. The output current is 0.6 A (I used battery instead of solar panel in picture).

[image]

And the phone charges but it is hanging on previous percentage. What's the problem? Can non-chargeable battery charge rechargeable battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your poor little 9V battery has probably given up its last electron.

9V batteries don't contain much energy, and you are throwing away a lot of that in the 7805.

If you draw 0.6A through it, you will be dropping 4 volts at 0.6A.  That's 2.4Watts being wasted.  That's nearly as much as actually makes it to your phone.  You are throwing away half of what the battery can provide.

9V batteries are rated at maybe 200mAh (200mAh at 9V gives 1.8Wh.)

Your phone battery is probably rated for 2000 mAh (2000mAh at 4.5 V gives 9Wh.)

But you are wasting half of the 1.8Wh from the battery just heating the 7805.  And, you can't get all of the energy of the battery because the 7805 won't work after the battery voltage drops below about 7 or 8 Volts.  The 7508 needs 2 to 3 Volts of difference between input and output to work.

So, you are wasting a lot of energy in the 7805, and most of what is left you can't get out of the battery.

---

Solution:

1. Don't use 9Volt radio batteries to charge a phone.  Use something with more capacity, like AA cells.
2. Don't use a linear regulator like the 7805.  Use a switching regulator.  They are more efficient by far.

Use a couple of AA cells in parallel and a boost converter to make 5V out of the 1.5V from the AA cells.

You could use the 7805 solution if you have something beefier to power it.  You could use it to charge your phone from a car battery, for example.  You'd need a big heat sink to cool it, though.  From 13V to 5V is 8 Volts difference.  At .6A, that'd be at least 5Watts of power wasted as heat.

Comment: So what is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone battery is probably not charging fast enough to rise in percentage.

As JRE says very weak power supply and alot of it is being wasted. Try using a BUCK CONVERTER and ideally get higher mAh battery. If you require a smooth power line then you could boost slightly above what you require and then a linear regulator to smooth out the voltage.